# Build instance, save and associate with one query

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using `.build` to create a model instance, which is later saved.

```
const modelInstance = sequelize.models.SomeModel.build({
  someKey: 'someValue',
  // ...
});
```

Later on after conditionally adding various properties, I'm calling `.save()`, followed by associating the record with another model.

```
modelInstance.save().then((modelInstance) => {
  modelInstance.setParent(parentInstance);
});
```

I've found that if I call `.setParent()` before `.save()`, that an empty `SomeModel` record is placed into the database.  Therefore, I have to call `.save()` first.  However, this requires two queries.

How can I use `.build()`/`.save()` with `.set<x>` in a single query?

Comment: Why are you building model ? is that also included in part of checking conditions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your parent is not already saved, you can save it at the same time this way :

```
return SomeModel.create({
  someKey: 'someValue',
  parent: {
    parentKey: 'parentValue'
  }
}, {
  include: [{
    association: ParentModel
  }]
});
```

If the parent instance is already saved (eg comes from a findOne for example), then your solution is correct. Just a thing : you should probably return the second promise :

```
modelInstance.save().then((modelInstance) => {
  return modelInstance.setParent(parentInstance);
});
```

If the parent instance exists and you really dont want to make those two requests, maybe you could just figure out how your association is made, and make it without sequelize. For example, if the association is defined by a foreign key to the parent, you could just save it this way :

```
return SomeModel.create({
  someKey: 'someValue',
  parentId: parentInstance.id
});
```

But of course, this would mean the object returned does not contain the parent property, you would have to make a `getParent()` after to retrieve it, which would result in a second request.